# Adding a dynamic value (date) in customFields LogstashEncoder

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-configuration, logstash-logback-encoder

First, just to give some insight about the architecture:

- There are several microservices running in Kubernetes, and two teams manage those services.
- There is a single elasticsearch cluster on which all the logs from Kubernetes are pushed.
- Both teams have different index names (for example, logstash-team1, logstash-team2)

Our logback configuration:

```
    <appender name="STDOUT_JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <providers>
                <contextName>
                    <fieldName>app</fieldName>
                </contextName>
                <timestamp>
                    <fieldName>timestamp</fieldName>
                    <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
                <loggerName>
                    <fieldName>logger</fieldName>
                </loggerName>
                <logLevel>
                    <fieldName>level</fieldName>
                </logLevel>
                <callerData>
                    <classFieldName>class</classFieldName>
                    <methodFieldName>method</methodFieldName>
                    <lineFieldName>line</lineFieldName>
                    <fileFieldName>file</fileFieldName>
                </callerData>
                <threadName>
                    <fieldName>thread</fieldName>
                </threadName>
                <mdc />
                <arguments>
                    <includeNonStructuredArguments>false</includeNonStructuredArguments>
                </arguments>
                <stackTrace>
                    <fieldName>stack</fieldName>
                </stackTrace>
                <message>
                    <fieldName>message</fieldName>
                </message>
            </providers>
            <customFields>{"esindex": "logstash-team1"}</customFields>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

- Everything works fine with this, however the logs on Kibana are not deleted after 30 days. We figured that if we add date in the `esindex` field, it might solve the problem (there maybe other solutions too, that I'm not aware of).
- So the `esindex` should look something like this: `logstash-team1-%d{yyyy-mm-dd}`.

Is there a way to do this? 
Or is there a way to delete logs, after 30 days, without appending date in index name?

Answer (score 1):

To specify a JSON field with a dynamic value that includes the date, you can use the `pattern` provider, like this:

```xml
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <contextName>
                    <fieldName>app</fieldName>
                </contextName>
                <timestamp>
                    <fieldName>timestamp</fieldName>
                    <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
                </timestamp>
                ... other providers ...
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>{"esindex": "logstash-team1-%date{yyyy-MM-dd,UTC}"}</pattern>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```